# Running python programs in Atom on Windows

Tags: atom-editor

When I try to run python on Atom Windows gives me an error message saying they cannot find 'python' (as shown in image).

[image: Error message. "Windows cannot find 'python'"]

So far I have installed atom-run-python, atom-run, autocomplete-python, and python packages. Can someone please explain why I am getting the error message and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: You need to add the directory where `python.exe` is installed to your system `PATH` variable. You can do this when you (re)install Python or manually edit your environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add python to your system `PATH` You can search how to do this in google.